# Javascript Button - method will not be invoked after onClick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

why will the method getLinkToFile not be invoked?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page for object fbcontrol</title>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        ...

        function getLinkToFile()
        {
        alert("alert");
        }

        ...

    </script>

<body onload="load()">

<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="GetLink_textField" VALUE="Geben Sie den Dateipfad an!" SIZE=50>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="GetLink_button" VALUE="Get link" onClick="javascript:getLinktoFile()">

</body>
</html>
```

The alert message is not shown! Whats the problem!?

Comment: remove `javascript:` (and change all the uppercase to lowercase please)

Comment: Your function is named `getLinkToFile` but you are calling the function `getLinktoFile` (lower case `t`), which does not exist. Also, having `javascript:` there is unnecessary and has the same effect as writing `foobar:` instead.

Comment: Using something like the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a good idea for these kinds of issues

Comment: Thanks a lot guys^^ F*** typo ;)

But I have another question:

if the fuction getLinkToFile expect a string as parameter how do I pass the parameter?

    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="GetLink_button" VALUE="Get link" onClick="javascript:getLinktoFile(??????????)">

Comment: `onClick="getLinkToFile('somethinghere')"` notice the 2 sets of quotes (single and double quotes) .... note : you dont need the `javascript:` bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need the `javascript:` bit and the function has an upper case T on to :

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="GetLink_button" VALUE="Get link" onClick="getLinkToFile()">
```

will work fine

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
onClick="getLinktoFile()"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use onclick attribute, you won't use 'javascript:' so:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="GetLink_button" VALUE="Get link" onClick="getLinktoFile()">
```

Comment: That's not the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

You have `getLinkToFile()` defined but are calling `getLinktoFile` (lowercase t in 'to').

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.
Your function name has an uppercase `T`.